# Power Apps, button to change required data cards to false

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, formula

I am trying to switch all required datacards to false with the click of a button.

In SharePoint they are NOT required.

but I cant seem to get this to work, any tips?

```
Q1_DataCard1.Required=false;
Q2_DataCard1.Required=false;
Q2a_DataCard1.Required=false;
Q2b_DataCard1.Required=false;
Q2c_DataCard1.Required=false;
Q2d_DataCard1.Required=false;
Q2e_DataCard1.Required=false;
Q2f_DataCard1.Required=false;
Q2g_DataCard1.Required=false;
Q3_DataCard1.Required=false;
Q4_DataCard1.Required=false;
Q5_DataCard1.Required=false;
Q6_DataCard1.Required=false;
Q7_DataCard1.Required=false;
Q8_DataCard1.Required=false;
Q9_DataCard1.Required=false;
SubmitForm(EditForm1_1);Refresh('Questionnaire');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one variable in `onStart` of `App` object or in `onVisible` of screen control like:

```
Set(isRequired, true);
```

You can set initial value to true or false as per your requirements.

Then use this variable to set `Required` property of all data cards. Set `Required` property directly to:

```
isRequired
```

Then you can change it's value on button click. Set `OnSelect` property of button control to:

```
Set(isRequired, false);
```